# How do I print number of rows inserted in a table using UTL_FILE in Oracle 10g?

Tags: database, logging, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, utl-file

I have a table TEST_TABLE in DB and I want to insert some values in it using a stored procedure. How do i print the number of rows that are inserted in TEST_TABLE after the SP has completed ??...I want to do this using UTL_FILE package and want a text file to be generated to monitor the data load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example based on HR schema - I'm inserting some rows from DEPARTMENTS table into DEPT_TEST. Number of rows being inserted can be retrieved through `SQL%ROWCOUNT` which returns number of rows processed by the last DML statement (the last executed before you call SQL%ROWCOUNT).

The procedure itself is kind of *stupid* - it "simulates" what I think yours does - inserts some rows, then inserts some more, etc. UTL_FILE usage is understandable, I suppose (gee, what would *FOPEN* or *FWRITE* do?). I'm writing values into TEST.TXT located in my EXT_DIR directory (which is, actually, C:\TEMP).

Note that - if you don't already have it - you should first create directory (connected as SYS) and grant READ/WRITE privileges to user which is going to use it (HR in my case).

OK then, here we go:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect hr/hr@xe
Connected.

SQL> create table dept_test as select * From departments where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_file utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    l_file := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'test.txt', 'w');
  5
  6    insert into dept_test (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
  7      select department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
  8        from departments
  9        where department_id between 0 and 150;
 10      utl_file.put_line(l_file, to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') ||
 11        ': Inserted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows');
 12
 13    insert into dept_test (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
 14      select department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
 15        from departments
 16        where department_id between 151 and 300;
 17      utl_file.put_line(l_file, to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') ||
 18        ': Inserted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows');
 19
 20    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 21  end;
 22  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> $type c:\temp\test.txt
12:32:51: Inserted 15 rows
12:32:51: Inserted 12 rows

SQL>
```

**However**, if I may, I'd suggest another approach - logging into a database. In order to do that, you need a log table and a procedure which utilizes `autonomous_transaction` pragma (so that you could COMMIT inserts, without affecting transaction performed by a caller).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE a1_log
  2  (
  3     id      NUMBER,
  4     datum   DATE,
  5     desc    VARCHAR2 (200)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seqlog START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a1_p_log (par_description IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  4  BEGIN
  5     INSERT INTO a1_log
  6        SELECT seqlog.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE, par_description FROM DUAL;
  7
  8     COMMIT;
  9  END a1_p_log;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Now, the initial "inserting" procedure would look like this:

```
SQL> begin
  2    insert into dept_test (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
  3      select department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
  4        from departments
  5        where department_id between 0 and 150;
  6      a1_p_log('Inserted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows');
  7
  8    insert into dept_test (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
  9      select department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
 10        from departments
 11        where department_id between 151 and 300;
 12      a1_p_log('Inserted ' || sql%rowcount || ' rows');
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> col description format a40
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From a1_log;

        ID DATUM    DESCRIPTION
---------- -------- ----------------------------------------
         1 12:52:08 Inserted 15 rows
         2 12:52:08 Inserted 12 rows

SQL>
```

In my opinion, this is a simpler option and I'd suggest you to use it instead of the UTL_FILE option, but - at the end, it's up to you.